# Background Img Div (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to build a module of span8 width and varying height. There is an image which will define the height of the div, and text that is positioned on top of the image. I am having trouble trying to figure out how prevent part of my image from being cropped when Bootstrap resizes the div.

In addition, I'm having trouble figuring out how to position my text boxes. I am trying to have two text boxes - one positioned at 0% vertical, and the second at 50% vertical.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12 promo">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="topText span24">
                    Text positioned on the top half
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="botText span24">
                    Text positioned on the bottom half
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.promo { height: 100%; }
.promo .content { width: 100%; height: 100%; background:url(http://www.placehold.it/470x188) no-repeat; }    
.promo .content .row-fluid { height: 50px; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting a `min-height` property? This will set a minimum height so your image won't be cut off.

I would try setting both divs to `height:50%;`, this should give you the right effect.

Comment: Sorry, which div do I set to `height:50%;`?

Comment: I also will not know the height of my images as they are all of varying sizes. Only the width is consistent.